# Binary tree traversal in c

Tags: c

Can someone please explain what could be wrong with this code, I have been trying to look for the problem but it is still giving me these errors:

```
prog.c: In function 'inorder':
prog.c:43:20: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'struct node *' [-Wformat=]
             printf("\n%d", t->left);
                ^
prog.c:44:21: warning: passing argument 1 of 'inorder' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
             inorder(t->data);
                 ^
prog.c:39:9: note: expected 'node * {aka struct node *}' but argument is of type 'int'
     int inorder(node *t)
     ^
prog.c: In function 'postorder':
prog.c:52:20: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'struct node *' [-Wformat=]
             printf("\n%d", t->left);
                    ^
prog.c:54:23: warning: passing argument 1 of 'postorder' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
             postorder(t->data);
                   ^
prog.c:48:13: note: expected 'node * {aka struct node *}' but argument is of type 'int'
         int postorder(node *t)
             ^
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:65:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'preorder' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 preorder(root);
 ^
prog.c:67:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'inorder' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 inorder(root);
 ^
prog.c:69:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'postorder' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 postorder(root);
 ^
/tmp/ccXklWoM.o: In function `main':
c4068222a0281abc5ccfae03851cee26.c:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `preorder'
c4068222a0281abc5ccfae03851cee26.c:(.text+0xf9): undefined reference to `inorder'
c4068222a0281abc5ccfae03851cee26.c:(.text+0x114): undefined reference to `postorder'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And here is the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct node

     {
      int data;
      struct node *left;
      struct node *right;
      }node;

node *create()

    {
        node *p;
        int x;
        printf("Enter data (-1 for no data): ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if(x==-1)
        {

    return NULL;
    }
    else{
        p=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("Enter left child node: \n");
        p->left=create();
        printf("Enter right child node: \n");
        p->right=create();
        return p;
    }

    int preorder(node *t)
    {
        if(t!=NULL)
        {
            printf("\n%d", t->data);
            preorder(t->left);
            preorder(t->right);
        }
    }

    int inorder(node *t)
    {
        if(t!=NULL)
        {
            printf("\n%d", t->left);
            inorder(t->data);
           inorder(t->right);
        }

        int postorder(node *t)
    {
        if(t!=NULL)
        {
            printf("\n%d", t->left);
            postorder(t->right);
            postorder(t->data);
        }
    }
    }
}

int main()
{
  node *root;
  root=create();
  printf("\nThe preorder traversal is: \n");
  preorder(root);
  printf("\nThe inorder traversal is: \n");
  inorder(root);
  printf("\nThe postorder traversal is: \n");
  postorder(root);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: These errors are telling you where the problem is. SO is not a debugging tool, only post a question if you have made an attempt in resolving the problem and have a **specific** question about how to achieve certain thing or why does something work certain way.

Comment: You are not returning anything from `preorder` so it must be of return type `void`.

Comment: You have tried to print an address using `%d` specifier. And in the traversal functions you always pass as parameter a `node*` not an `int`. But you have errorneously  done so in `inorder` function.

Comment: @sjaustirni Look, I know you are an expert but others being on this forum simply means they need help and are beginners like me. So please dont overlook my intentions  on this post

Comment: `inorder()` and `postorder()` are broken. E.g. `inorder()` prints `t->left` and tries to traverse into `t->data`. I.e. you re-ordered the node components but not the corresponding function calls. It's a funny error somehow (but probably not for you).

Comment: I am by no means an expert on this forum. However, as this site is [user-moderated](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) and I got your question popped up during the moderation, I wanted to make sure you understand what was wrong with your question so you could ask a better question next time.

Comment: @Scheff I hope I am not asking too much but how do I go about this problem (I'm really bad at C)

Comment: Read books, learn, practise, understand... You really should learn to use a debugger as it can show you step by step what happens. Please, concentrate on `inorder()`. Again: It **prints** `t->left` and **recurses** into `t->data`. Shouldn't it vice vs? I.e.: **recurse** into `t->left` and **print** `t->data`. IMHO, you could've done this error in any other language as well except that it wouldn't compile in most others. That's unlucky for you - in C it compiles successfully (or probably with some warnings) but is still wrong. Btw. often recommended: take warnings seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1. You have defined the function inorder, postorder and preorder in the create function. Place the closing brackets correctly and it will resolve that error.

2. In create function, you are not assigning the data to node. 

3. Inorder, postorder and preorder function needs of data type node* but you are passing of data type int at several places. That is the reasons of some warnings. 

4. I have written the same code based on your implementation. I complied with gcc and run a test. It seems okay. Have a look at it for your reference. 
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
      int data;
      struct node *left;
      struct node *right;
};

typedef struct node node; 
node *create()
{

    int x;
    printf("Enter data (-1 for no data): ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    if(x==-1)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        node *p;
        p=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        p->data = x;
        printf("Enter left child node: \n");
        p->left=create();
        printf("Enter right child node: \n");
        p->right=create();
        return p;
    }
}

void preorder(node *t)
{
    if(t!=NULL)
    {
            printf("\n%d", t->data);
            preorder(t->left);
            preorder(t->right);
    }
    return; 
}

void inorder(node *t)
{

    if(t != NULL)
    {
        inorder(t->left);
        printf("%d\n", (t->data));
        inorder(t->right);
    }

    return;
}

void postorder(node *t)
{
    if(t!=NULL)
    {
        postorder(t->left);
        postorder(t->right);
        printf("%d\n", (t->data));
    }
    return; 
}



int main()
{
  node *root;
  root=create();
  printf("\nThe preorder traversal is: \n");
  preorder(root);
  printf("\nThe inorder traversal is: \n");
  inorder(root);
  printf("\nThe postorder traversal is: \n");
  postorder(root);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Your code is not well formatted. You forgot to close the curly brackets `}`. You need to close them after writing your function:
   `void foo(){//code for function}`.
2. You cannot print a pointer using `%d`. If you want to print the value of your node try `printf("\n%d", t->data)`. If you want to print a pointer try using `%p`.
3. You are not saving the read value `x`.
4. You are not traversing the tree as you should. Google it and read more about it.

Formatted code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} node;

node *create() {
    node *p;
    int x;
    printf("Enter data (-1 for no data): ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    if (x == -1) {

        return NULL;
    } else {
        p = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
        //save read value
        p->data=x;
        printf("Enter left child node: \n");
        p->left = create();
        printf("Enter right child node: \n");
        p->right = create();
        return p;
    }
}

//function is not returning anything so its return type should be void
void preorder(node *t) {
    if (t != NULL) {
        //key left right
        printf("\n%d", t->data);
        preorder(t->left);
        preorder(t->right);
    }
}

void inorder(node *t) {
    if (t != NULL) {
        //left key right
        inorder(t->left);
        printf("\n%d", t->data);
        inorder(t->right);
    }
}

void postorder(node *t) {
    if (t != NULL) {
        //left right key
        postorder(t->right);
        postorder(t->left);
        printf("\n%d", t->data);
    }
}

int main() {
    node *root;
    root = create();
    printf("\nThe preorder traversal is: \n");
    preorder(root);
    printf("\nThe inorder traversal is: \n");
    inorder(root);
    printf("\nThe postorder traversal is: \n");
    postorder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Changed function return type of `preorder`, `inorder` and `postorder`, from `int` to `void`

Answer (score 1):

In your `preorder` `inorder` and `postoder` you make errors in the parameters:

```
       printf("\n%d", t->left);    // you can't print a node
       inorder(t->data);           // you can't traverse an integer
```

which should be:

```
       printf("\n%d", t->data);
       inorder(t->left);
```

In `create` you forget to assign the data:

```
       p->data= x;
```

You may be compiling as C++ instead of C. This explains the undefined references as you have the functions overloaded and the C++ compiler can't find the various overloaded functions. Compile as C.

Note: for preorder/inorder/postorder just move the print statement and recursively call the appropriate function.

Comment: At least it is better after last edit. I see your pedagogical intention as you leave it to the questioner to find the final solution. (That's why I answered with a comment instead of ready code.) However, all of our intentions are fruitless as (the other) Paul tries earn his first reputation.

Comment: Thank you all for the clarification... really hepled a lot